# autocomplete textbox in asp.net webservice

Tags: asp.net

I use master page and a script to open a popup window. This popup window has one textbox. I add an ajax autocomplete extender in the textbox. It runs and gets the values and I check the breakpoint, but it doesn't display the autovalues in the textbox. How can I solve this problem?

My code:

```
<ajaxToolkit:autocompleteextender ID="aceSearch" runat="server" TargetControlID="itemnametext" BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx" MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="5" CompletionInterval="100" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" ServicePath="CloudlistService.asmx"> 

</ajaxToolkit:autocompleteextender>
```

Comment: show us what you have tried some code

Comment: <ajaxToolkit:autocompleteextender  ID="aceSearch" runat="server" TargetControlID="itemnametext" BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx" 
MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="5" CompletionInterval="100" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" ServicePath="CloudlistService.asmx"  >        </ajaxToolkit:autocompleteextender>

Comment: Are you saying you can see the values in the pop up window but not in the main site?

Comment: i am see the values in site,but not in pop up window

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is related to the `z-index` of the popup and the autocomplete.

the autocomplete must have a heigher `z-index`

you can achieve that by the property `CompletionListCssClass` of the autocomplete

Comment: how to set the CompletionListCssClass Z-index?

Comment: in this CompletionListCssClass property you state the CSS Class name.
in the Class style (in css file or <style>) you set the z-index property

Comment: sorry sarath, couldn't get what you mean in your last comment

Comment: i set the Z-index in CompletionListCssClass property in 200.But the textbox not display autocomplete values..

Comment: can you try and take the TextBox outside the popup and see if the autocomplete results show? just to make sure its the z-index that is making the problem.
Also, try using the page inspectors (right-click, Inspect elemnt in Chrome) and try to see the z-index of the autocomplete <ul> tag at the end of the page, and the popup z-index